# R multiplot write plot to file grid package

Tags: r, plot, grid

I have a function to create a multiplot (plot with many sub plots) and to write it to file.

```
multiplot <- function(plotlist=NULL, cols) {
  require(grid)

  # Make a list from the ... arguments and plotlist
  plots <- c(plotlist)

  numPlots = length(plots)

  # Make the panel
  plotCols = cols                       # Number of columns of plots
  plotRows = ceiling(numPlots/plotCols) # Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols

  # Set up the page
  grid.newpage()
  pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(plotRows, plotCols)))
  vplayout <- function(x, y)
    viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)

  # Make each plot, in the correct location
  for (i in 1:numPlots) {
    curRow = ceiling(i/plotCols)
    curCol = (i-1) %% plotCols + 1
    print(plots[[i]], vp = vplayout(curRow, curCol ))
    #title(paste(product_name,'_ROC___AUC = ', mroc$auc))
  }

}
```

and a call to the function create the following plot:

```
filepath <- paste(filepath,'/','Norm_Method_',norm_method,'.jpg',sep="")
jpeg(filepath)  
#multiplot(list(ggplot1,ggplot2,ggplot3,ggplot4,ggplot5,ggplot6,ggplot7,ggplot8,linear_pred,roc.plot), cols=4)
multiplot(list(ggplot1,ggplot2,ggplot3,ggplot4,ggplot5,ggplot6,ggplot7,ggplot8,linear_pred), cols=3)
dev.off()
```

here is the faulty plot look:
[image]

obviously the picture needs scratching so I maximized it in RStudio and saved manually the results look much better: [image]
any idea how to write it automatically to file in the "maximized window" better version of the plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would recommend using the `arrangeGrob` function from the package `gridExtra`.

Some sample code is below:

```
require(ggplot2)

require(gridExtra)

data(iris)

p<-ggplot(iris)

a<-p+geom_histogram(aes(x=Sepal.Length))+ ggtitle("A plot")
b<-p+geom_histogram(aes(x=Sepal.Width))+ ggtitle("another PLOT")
c<-p+geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length))+ggtitle("PLOT CITY")
a2<-p+geom_histogram(aes(x=Sepal.Length))+ ggtitle("A plot")
b2<-p+geom_histogram(aes(x=Sepal.Width))+ ggtitle("another PLOT")
c2<-p+geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length))+ggtitle("PLOT CITY")

grobula <- arrangeGrob(a,b,c,a2,b2,c2 ,ncol=3, nrow=2,
                             main = textGrob("some plots", gp = gpar(fontsize=18, fontface="bold.italic", fontsize=18)),
                             sub = textGrob("some subtitle", x=0, hjust=-0.5, vjust=0.1, gp = gpar(fontface = "italic", fontsize = 15)))
```

This outputs an object that I called `grobula`. You can then print or save the object as you would a normal ggplot object (e.g. `print(grobula)` or `ggsave(grobula,file=x.pdf)`.

This makes your function a little redundant; you can just plug the appropriate values into `ncol` and `nrow` in `arrangeGrob`.

Finally, to specify plot size in ggsave you can modify the `width` and `height` parameters. You may also need to adjust various text sizes of titles and things to make everything fit in your final combined plot. You can modify text size in ggplot titles by changing the `element.text` parameters. You can find the appropriate documentation here.

http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/theme.html

[image]

Comment: The same problem appears when I try to save, the plot turns out to look squashed. Again, if before saving I maximize the windows of the plot in RStudio and then save the plot look fine. Is there a way to tell R maximize the plot window before saving ?